# How to solve insert() missing 1 required positional argument:'column_values' problem from Python Sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

all worked nice bad now it return error

```py
def add_expense(raw_message):
    chat_id         = types.User.get_current().id
    parsed_message  = _parse_message(raw_message)
    category        = Categories().get_category(parsed_message.category_text)
    inserted_row_id = db.insert("expense", {"user_id": chat_id, 
    "amount": parsed_message.amount, "created": _get_now_formatted(),  
    "category_codename": category.codename, "raw_text": raw_message})

    return Expense(id=None, amount=parsed_message.amount, category_name=category.name)
```

'column_values' 
TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument:

---

`db.insert` is defined elsewhere as:

```
def insert(id,table, column_values): 
    columns = ', '.join( column_values.keys() )
    values = [tuple(column_values.values())]
    placeholders = ", ".join( "?" * len(column_values.keys()) )  
    cursor.executemany( f"INSERT INTO {table} "
                        f"({columns}) "
                        f"VALUES ({placeholders})", values)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: What is `db.insert`?

Comment: its from my module

Comment: It does matter and should have been an edit to the question. I have done it for you.

Comment: It is weird: if that code was used, and if `insert` is a method, it should not raise this error. I suspect you have hidden a name or a module somewhere...

Comment: @Serge Ballesta so problem is modules?

Comment: `db.insert` takes 3 arguments; `inserted_row_id` sends 2 arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

three years passed, and I found the answer to my question in the morning of that day. At that time, I was still a little familiar with programming. The problem turned out to be in another module. As I remember, there was one extra letter a, so the python did not want to compile and the whole code did not work. Conclusion look carefully and consciously

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34007805)